# fill each cell with different color

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I create 10*10 array, I want to fill each cell in the 2D array with different color using canvas. I try to do it only with canvas but next stage I need to check each cell has different color from his Neighbor.
any ideas?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cols = 10;
var rows = 10;
var board = [];
function start() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        board[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {    
            //add code here
        }

    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you open the `canvas` doc page ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: what colors values? you should start defining these.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service. Do some research into random colors

Comment: But I have to check that all the neighbors of each cell are a different color from it. That's why I switched to a two-dimensional array instead only draw on canvas and I want to go over each cell and fill it randomly and if one of its neighbors in the selected color then switch color

Comment: I cannot see the array

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution:

```js
function genBoard(cols, rows) {
  let board = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    board[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      [
        board[i - 1] && board[i - 1][j] || null,
        board[i][j - 1] || null
      ].reduce((colorA, colorB) => {
        do {
          board[i][j] = '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
        } while (colorA === board[i][j] || colorB === board[i][j])
      });
    }
  }
  
  return board;
}

let colorsBoard = genBoard(5, 5);
console.log(JSON.stringify(colorsBoard));

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let [x, y, width, height] = [0, 0, 50, 50];

colorsBoard.forEach((row, i) => row.forEach((color, j) => {
  [x, y] = [width * j, height * i];
  context.moveTo(x, y);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

First generate your colors, then render with canvas.

When setting each color value in the 2d array, check if it is already at index `[i - 1, j]` and/or `[i, j - 1]`. If so change it using a `do ... while` loop.